# problem at : java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)

Tags: java, numberformatexception

> I want to withdraw money (tfSommeRetrait) , and i have problem in the
>   ligne: 
>           int res = Integer.parseInt(som1) - Integer.parseInt(som2.replace(" ",""));

```
            public void retraitNormal() throws SQLException {

        try {
            ConnectionMysql connectionMysql = new ConnectionMysql();//instance of connection
            Connection connection = connectionMysql.getConnection();

            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            String  som1 = "SELECT SOMME FROM compte WHERE NUM_Compte ='"+tfNumCRetrait.getText()+"'";
            String som2 = tfSommeRetrait.getText();

            int res = Integer.parseInt(som1) - Integer.parseInt(som2.replace(" ",""));

            String resultat = String.valueOf(res);

            String query = "UPDATE compte SET SOMME = 'resultat' WHERE NUM_Compte='"+tfSommeRetrait.getText()+"' ";
            statement.executeUpdate(query);

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
```

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "SELECT SOMME FROM
>   compte WHERE NUM_Compte ='12'"
>             at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
>             at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
>             at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
>             at Caissier.Caissier.retraitNormal(Caissier.java:250)

Comment: You are trying to parse a SQL query as an int - I guess you're intending to execute that query, and parse the result as an int.

Comment: So ,where is the problem?

Comment: Line 250, at `Integer.parseInt(som1)`.

Comment: Yeah i wanna cast String to an Integer for the - operation

Comment: There is no way to turn a string like "SELECT SOMME FROM compte..." into an integer wiith ```Integer.parseInt```; parseInt handles strings like "12345".  You need to present that string to your database and process the result.

Comment: @Sara, as already pointed by Andy, you should first execute your query, before trying to cast the result, please, read this [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html), you are missing a few things, but my guesses are that the `ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query)` instruction on the provided link can be of help.

Comment: In time, not a java programmer here, but would make a lot of sense to me to iterate over the results - or at least get the first one if your query is intended to do so - on the `rs` using the `while (rs.next())` instruction, to just then perform the desired cast, assuming that your `SOMME` column is an integer on the database.

Answer (score 1):

In your code when it executes *Integer.parseInt(som1)* the variable som1 has this value = "SELECT SOMME FROM compte WHERE NUM_Compte...." so it is normal the error. Your som1 string has to be a numeber if you want parse it to an Integer.

```
String  som1 = "SELECT SOMME FROM compte WHERE NUM_Compte ='"+tfNumCRetrait.getText()+"'";
String som2 = tfSommeRetrait.getText();

int res = Integer.parseInt(som1) - Integer.parseInt(som2.replace(" ",""));
```